# Return the CSS values from CSS attributes using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
$string = 'font-size:12em;';

$pattern = '@:[A-Za-z0-9.]+;@i';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` returns:

```
Array ( [0] => :12em; )
```

However, why is the `:` and `;` returned? How can I get it to not return those colons and only return the CSS value `12em`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first element in that array is the whole match. Use a capturing group, and the second element (or use lookarounds).

Example:

```
preg_match('/:\s*(\w[^;}]*?)\s*[;}]/', $string, $matches);
print $matches[1];
```

---

Note that things like these will not work in all cases. Comments and more complicated statements could break it.

Example:

```
/* foo: bar; */
foo: url("bar?q=:x;");
```

Comment: That is a good point, all I am looking for really is the CSS values ending in `em` and `px` - maybe I should use these to narrow things down? How would you implement this in your regex?

Comment: @Abs, try `/:\s*(\w[^;}]*?(?:em|px))\s*[;}]/`

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern instead:

```
@(?<=:)[A-Za-z0-9.]+(?=;)@i
```

The explanation is that you the `(?<=)` and `(?=)` are respectively lookbehind and lookahead groups. Which means they aren't captured as part of your match.

---

**Edit** For handling `%`'s +more

```
@(?<=:)[^;]+@i
```

Comment: That works well. However, when I try it on `width:10%` it doesn't seem to return any value? Maybe the `%` is a special character?